# R - extract() function - buffer option not working

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, r, buffer, extract

I'm trying to extract a mean value from multiple pixels of raster file "r"  for a vector shapefile "v", by using the r extract function (see `?raster::extract`)

Since some of the file "v" shapes falls outside the raster map (e.g. cities on a coast), and given that the NA values are already transformed to zeros, I extract by using a buffer, so that the latter would still get a reasonable value as a mean.

Assuming a buffer of 1000 meters, the code is then:

`extracted_values <- extract(r, v, fun=mean, buffer = 1000)`

---

Following @Robert’s advice I am adding a reproducible example that mimics my data situation, and also compares with the solution proposed by @Jeffrey:

```
# Generate a raster and change the crs to the ones of my data
r <- raster(ncol=1000, nrow=1000, xmx=-80, xmn=-150, ymn=20, ymx=60)
values(r) <- runif(ncell(r))
r <- projectRaster(r, crs = "+proj=longlat +a=6367470 +b=6367470 +no_defs ",method = "bilinear")
# Set a part of the raster equal to zero
r[1:800000] = 0

# generate sample polygon
crdref <- CRS('+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84')
lon <- c(-116.8, -114.2, -112.9, -111.9, -114.2, -115.4, -117.7)
lat <- c(41.3, 42.9, 42.4, 39.8, 37.6, 38.3, 37.6)
lonlat <- cbind(lon, lat)
v <- spPolygons(lonlat, crs=crdref)
v <- spTransform(x = v, CRSobj = crs(r)) # Now these represents the starting data situation

# convert to 3857 to have distances in meters
r <- projectRaster(r, crs = "+init=epsg:3857")
v <- spTransform(x = v, CRSobj = crs(r)) 
# I add a "buffered" version to confirm visually that now the buffered polygon intersects the raster pixels >0
v_buf <- gBuffer(v,width=1500000)  
plot(r)
plot(v, add = TRUE)
plot(v_buf, add=TRUE) 

# Results of extract: 
no_buf <- extract(r, v, fun=mean)
print(no_buf)
buf <- extract(r, v, fun=mean, buffer=1500000)
print(buf)
buf_higher <- extract(r, v, fun=mean, buffer=1600000)
print(buf_higher)
buf_weights <- extract(r, v, fun=mean, buffer=1500000, weights= T, normalizeWeights = T)
print(buf_weights)

# with extract_exact and using the v_buf polygon (already with buffer)
buf_exact <- exact_extract(r, v_buf, 'weighted_mean', weights = 'area')
print(buf_exact)

# Does it change increasing the buffer?
v_buf2 <- gBuffer(v,width=1600000)  
buf_exact2 <- exact_extract(r, v_buf2, 'weighted_mean', weights = 'area')
print(buf_exact2)
```

It seems however that the buffer option is not affecting the final result, whether by excluding it, or by increasing/decreasing the number of meters.

---

I am adding the result of show(r), edited for privacy in the source and names fields. In any case the original raster file is taken from a GRIB file from the "ERA5-Land hourly data from 1981 to present":

```
class      : RasterLayer 
band       : 1  (of  156  bands)
dimensions : 1801, 3600, 6483600  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.1, 0.1  (x, y)
extent     : -0.05, 359.95, -90.05, 90.05  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +a=6367470 +b=6367470 +no_defs
source     : FILENAME.grib 
names      : NAMES
```

Why is the buffer option not affecting the mean result for the extract function?

---

Following the advice by @Jeffrey the procedure works, in the sense that increasing the buffer causes the extracted mean value to change (as correctly, the polygons with buffer extra space now cover pixels with values different than zero). Here is the revised code (notice that here the area is weighted):

```
library(exactextractr)
library(rgeos)

r <- projectRaster(r, crs = "+init=epsg:3857")
v <- spTransform(x = v, CRSobj = crs(r))  
v <- gBuffer(v,width=1000, byid = T)

extracted_values <- exact_extract(r, v, 'weighted_mean', weights = 'area', force_df = T, append_cols = T)
```

Comment: Both the raster and vector need to be in a distance base projection (eg., meters). The developer of raster contributes to this forum so, he will likely chime in here if there is an actual package issue. However, in the meantime I would recommend calculating a buffer using `rgeos::rBuffer` (for sp objects) or `sf::st_buffer` (for sf objects) then using `exactextract::exact_extract` for returning the mean raster values. It will be a massive speed improvement and offers the option of a weighted mean using the fractional intersection of cells (ie., area weighted).

Comment: Dear Jeffrey, thank you very much for your answer. exact_extract() seems to provide the behavior that I was expecting. I included this suggestion in the main body of the question.

Answer (score 3):

Adding a buffer may not affect the result if the buffer is small, relative to the cell size of the raster.

You provide no reproducible example, or information on the data your using such as `show(raster)` or `head(points)` making it very difficult to help you. Can you please edit your question and include some of that?

You seem to be barking up the tree with changing the coordinate reference system (CRS). `raster::extract` should work irrespective of whether the CRS is planar or angular (lonlat). You appear to be setting a CRS to your data on the basis of what you *want it to be*. That is not valid. If need be, it should only be set to what it *is*.

(You can put a post-it with "Rolls-Royce" on your bicycle --- but don't expect a chauffeur to appear and take you for a spin.)

See `spTransform` to change a crs.

You also say that "the units are in degrees and as explained in the extract function help file, this does not make the buffer option to work". That is not correct. Where does it say that?